getActiveRange() function is broken
I woke up this morning to find a program I made was encountering errors. After some testing I found the getActiveRange() function was no longer returning the correct values in my sheet.
I made a test sheet to troubleshoot the issue, and found that getActiveRange() is permanently returning the value of cell A1, rather than the highlighted cells. I know the sheet connection is fine because I had the program write the contents to another cell in the sheet and it is updating correctly.
Any Ideas on what needs to be changed? Did google break something?
const SHEET_ID = "abc123";
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
.createMenu('Script Menu') 
.addItem('Test Names', 'testNames')
.addToUi();
  
}

function testNames(){
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
 var values = range.getValues();
 var startRow = range.getRow();
 Logger.log(values);
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue(values[i][0]);
 sheet.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue(values[i][1]);
 }
}

The script should copy the highlighted values into neighboring columns. It does not do so.

It doesn't make sense to include SpreadsheetApp.flush(); before making any change to the spreadsheet.

When you use openById it always opens the file on the server so the active range is always A1.  Specify the range you want in the function.

SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveRange is working fine, however, I understand that it's not working as you expect.
This happens because your script is opening the spreadsheet by using SpreadsheetApp.openById. When using this method, the  Google Apps Script engine doesn't get information about the the current cell, active range, selection, and related elements that depends on a spreadsheet opened by a user.
As the function is called by a menu item, you might have to use SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(). If you required the data from a different spreadsheet than the one containing the script, instead of SpreadsheetApp.openById(id), or instead of using SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveRange use one of the SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange methods, or SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange. You might have to adapt the rest of the script to the selected method.
Related

Google Sheets getActiveRange on change
Google Script getActiveRange
getActiveRange not returning current selection
is there a way to make getActiveRange() function work on a different spreadsheet?


Thank you! After changing the program to use getActiveSpreadsheet() I was able to retrieve the highlighted cells correctly. Sorry for the 'broken' title, I assumed something else had gone wrong.
